# Javascript Regex Problems

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Regex:

```
(o|a|os|as\$)\b
```

and I need to put in this format:

```
new RegExp('o|a|os|as' + '\\$' + '\\b', 'i');
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Unrelated, but `o|a|os|as` is equivalent to `[oa]s?`

Comment: `new RegExp('(o|a|os|as\\$)\\b')` ? or maybe `new RegExp('(o|a|os|as\\$)\\b', 'i')` ? Not sure what the format you refer to is, but both expressions correspond to the regex you posted, the second using the case-insensitive flag in addition.

Comment: What is the JavaScript format of `(o|a|os|as\$)\b`? Is it trully a regex pattern? Is it a string? It's not sure what it is as JavaScript regex pattern do begin and end with a slash.

Comment: Use `new RegExp('(' + 'o|a|os|as' + '\\$' + ')(?!\\w)', 'i')`